# Editting View Created by uiTableview class

Tags: iphone

I am new to iphone developement, just started learning uitableview class.

So i created a view and added tableview.Please let me know how can i move further to enable editing option for each cell.

Do i need to use accessory property to enable this option?

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on the table editing mode by setting your UITableView's "editing" to YES